# Simple Begginer Promise Chaining

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to programming and Javascript and have recently came along a problem I've found via my works training scheme, yet no one seems to have an adequate solution as of yet.

1. Write   your    own Promise class   with    syncThen    method.
   Example:

```
    let promise =   new MyPromise((resolve) =>  {
            console.log(1);
            resolve();
    }).synchThen(() =>  {
            console.log(2);
    }).then(()  =>  {
            console.log(3);
    })
    console.log(4);
    //1,    2,  4,  3
```

2. Write   ReversePromise  class   so  that    ‘then’  functions   are calling from    the end to
   the start.
   Example:

```
let promise =   new ReversePromise((resolve)    =>  {
console.log(1);
resolve();
})
.then(()    =>  console.log(2))
.then(()    =>  console.log(3))
.then(()    =>  console.log(4))
//1,    4,  3,  2
```

I've spent the last week or so, looking through docs so i'm aware of the basics of promises, what i was wondering was how to create the syncThen method as a means of chaining to the then() function?

The first part is fine ...

```js
        const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(1);
        setTimeout(() => resolve(4), 1000);
        }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        });
        console.log(2);
```

which shows logs
1,2,4 and i understand why, but unsure how to chain on the syncThen method?

Edit...

I've now just used chaining for the subsequent then methods, and its all simple enough, but the asyncThen method that the question is asking for is throwing me as is the reverse bit.

Additional Code again

```
console.log(1);
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
   resolve(4);
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
       resolve(3);
    });
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
      
})
console.log(2);
```

I think with the asyncThen function their after, they want a method where I can pass the returned promise and manipulate it to then chain on before or after then ()

Comment: Where is `syncThen` coming from? Sounds suspiciously like a mashup of `async` and `then`...

Comment: `MyPromise` receive a callback in the constructor. I believe that inside the constructor you should create a native `Promise` and pass the callback to it. The instance of this class has a method `syncThen`. It receive a function as callback and return Promise. You can chain this callback to the Promise you created in the constructor.

Comment: const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
console.log(1);
setTimeout(() => resolve(2), 1000);
}).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
}).then(() => {
console.log(4);
}).then(() => {
  console.log(3);
  })

Comment: @DigitalDrifter honestly i have no idea, was just going off what the question which seems to be quite vague. Mosh Feu thanks i'll have a look into that :).

Comment: My reading of this is that `syncThen` would be just what it sounds like.  It accepts a callback and synchronously calls it without waiting for the result to be known.  I would assume that its result is discarded.  As a learning exercise, this might be interesting.  But I don't see it as actually useful for anything.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I think Scott's understanding is correct, the purpose of the entire thing is a learning exercise, its just that bit which has confused me, thanks for the reply though, i've made additional changes just now, after the feedback about the promise constructor

Comment: "*Write your own Promise class with syncThen method*", "*Write ReversePromise class so that ‘then’ functions are calling from the end to the start.*" - these are horrible assignment tasks that thwart the core ideas of promises. I'd argue the latter is completely impossible even if the object is supposed to resemble a promise's `then` functionality in any way.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yeah I think your right, the whole point is a learning opportunity via training, i just got very bogged down in it, but the latest code that ill post now seems to get to the heart of it (I think).

Comment: Thanks all, i realise that its a silly exercise, my goal is to become as efficient as possible hence my desire to understand what these guys are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// index.js

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
  syncThen(fn) {
    const val = fn();
    return this.then(_ => val);
  }
}

exports.MyPromise = MyPromise;



// NEVER EVER WRITE A PROGRAM LIKE THIS!
// REVERSE PROMISE IS THE SILLIEST
// IDEA I HAVE EVER HEARD OF.
// IF YOU WRITE CODE LIKE THIS
// YOUR TEAMMATES WILL NOT LIKE YOU.
class ReversePromise extends Promise {
  constructor(fn) {
    super(_ => _());
    this.fn = fn;
    this.stack = [];
  }
  then(fn) {
    this.stack.push(fn);
    return this;
  }

  // not standard to promises
  // but you need some way to
  // say the chaining has completed
  run() {
    const p = new Promise(this.fn);
    let current = p;

    while (this.stack.length) {
      current = current.then(this.stack.pop());
    }

    return p;
  }
}

exports.ReversePromise = ReversePromise;
```

Call like:

```
const { MyPromise, ReversePromise } = require('.');

const myP = (new MyPromise(res => {console.log(1); res()})).syncThen(_ => console.log(2)).then(_ => console.log(3)); console.log(4);

const revP = (new ReversePromise(res => { console.log(1); res();})).then(_ => console.log(2)).then(_ => console.log(3)).then(_ => console.log(4)).run();
```

Comment: "ReversePromise" is so silly I would recommend to not use `extends Promise` at all. +1 for the warning alone :-)

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, i've just started on stack and can't upvote you until I get a score of > 15. But this helps tremendously, don't worry I wont use in a real world setting haha. My plan is to spend a great ammount of time learning vanilla js, becoming efficient then moving onto the react framework, i'm also learning leetcode questions as it helps me think logically. Do you have anything you can recommend in regards to becoming a better developer? Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: I think starting with vanilla js is a great way to go. It's also worth spending some time learning the nodejs core lib https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/. Programming is just like anything else, you need to put in the time to get better.

Comment: I can tell its silly - but very nice task (and job louis) for learning promises and some more advanced stuff of javascript - very nice exercise i think even some middles would have some struggles with it   btw jacob - learn typescript as well (its more like helping you in big project keeping types

Answer (score 1):

louisbuchbinder already handled the `ReversePromise` implementation.  I'm not certain that the version of `MyPromise` in that answer would actually work though.

Here is a version of `MyPromise` with its `synchThen` method.  It uses delegation rather than inheritance.  The `synchThen` method is entirely useless except for side-effects like writing to the console.  We can't do anything with the promise result, as this is running synchronously and the result hasn't yet been calculated.  Nor can the process calculating the result take advantage of any return from this function, as it's already off doing its asynchronous process.

So this is just as silly as `ReversePromise`.  But it does show one way to achieve it.

```js
const MyPromise = class {
  constructor (callback) {this.promise = new Promise (callback)}
  then (fn) {this.promise.then(fn); return this}
  synchThen (fn) {fn(); return this}
}

const promise = new MyPromise((resolve) => {
  console.log(1)
  resolve()
}).synchThen(() => {
  console.log(2)
}).then(() => {
  console.log(3)
})

console.log(4)
```

Comment: This helps alot, and seems to be a very elegant version of what I was trying to go for, thanks for this, I knew I was supposed to use syncThen to return the promise, but wasn't sure how.